# HTML5/CSS3 how to expand an anchor element to fit full size of it's li parent

Tags: html, css, html-lists, anchor, fill

I've got an unordered list which holds a few items. It's purpose is to become a navbar. The list is set up to be displayed as a table-row with each li element a table-cell, these elements each hold an anchor tag with the first one holding the logo. The issue is that the anchor elements are positioned to the bottom vertically and I can't find a way to center them.

Here's an image of the issue:

[image]

I've colored the `<a>` background green and `<li>` background red. As it's visible here the text anchor items are positioned to the bottom and I can't figure out how to:

a) position the anchor text to the vertical center
b) have the anchor fill the entire height of the parent li

I've tried adding `vertical-align: center;` to both li and a but it did not work.

Here are relevant pieces of my html/css code so far

HTML:

```
<body>
        <header class="mainHeader">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html"><img class="logo" src="logo.png" alt="index"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <footer></footer>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.mainHeader {
    background-color: #111;
    color: #999;

    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#111), to(#444));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#111, #444);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#111, #444);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#111, #444);
    background-image: linear-gradient(#111, #444);

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #777;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #777;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #777;

    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #777;

    overflow: hidden;
}

.logo {
    max-width: 130px;
    max-height: 170px;
}

.mainHeader ul{
    display: table-row;
}

.mainHeader li{
    width: 130px;
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: red;
}

.mainHeader a{
    display: block;
    background-color: green;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #999;
}
```

Comment: Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/VufHp/)?

Comment: @Harry Oh so it's middle and not center. Yes placing `vertical-align:middle;` centered the items. Thanks. Now is there a way to force the anchor elements (mainly it's background) to fill the entire height of it's parent list. So that in the example image the red color is not visible, only green.

Comment: Easiest way would be to make `li` background also as `green` :) (Coming to align, in HTML/CSS `center` is horizontal centering and `middle` is vertical centering :))

Comment: @Harry The point of red and green backgrounds was just to illustrate my point. What I really want is for anchor background to be the same height as it's container (the list) because I'm planning on adding an on hover animation. The way it currently is is that it only covers the height of the letters and because the image increases the height of all the li elements the anchor background doesn't expand, even when it's set as a block and even if i try to set its height to 100%. Basically I want the height of the anchor background to be the same as the height of a list cell

Comment: Understand mate, I am trying for a solution but have none yet. I think part of the reason could be that neither the parent `li` nor any child within it have a set `height`. The `img` also has only a `max-height`.

Comment: How about [this](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/VufHp/) sample? I have marked the modified items with inline comments.

Comment: Did that previous fiddle help mate?

Comment: @Harry I apologize for not replying earlier, I wasn't near a PC. I just got back so I haven't tested it yet but it looks like what I want. Thanks for your help bro.

Comment: No worries mate, I will update my answer with the latest version. Please mark it accepted and if there are any issues do let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify your CSS as below to get the expected behavior. Refer inline comments for modified items.

```
.logo {
    max-width: 130px;
    max-height: 170px;
    vertical-align: middle; /* added */
}
.mainHeader li {
    width: 130px;
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: red;
    vertical-align: middle; /* to position contents in middle of nav bar */
    line-height: 150px; /* added */
}
.mainHeader a {
    display: inline-block; /* modified to support vertical-align */
    width: 100%;
    background-color: green;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #999;
}
```

[**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/VufHp/)

Comment: This doesn't work if you have an unknown amount of text... If one of the cells overflow to the next line, that one will grow larger than the rest. Basically your answer only works for a static height. See an example here where all I did was decrease the `line-height` and increase the amount of text. http://jsfiddle.net/Tn5DG/1/